# Javascript another class property access

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript class contain the following code and i saved it as globalrates.js file

```
$(function() {
    setInterval('rates.set_rates()',1000);
});

rates = {

    marketstatus: {
        'goldrate': '',
        'status': ''
    },

    set_rates : function() {
        var my_Date = new Date();
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:90/appname/rateXml.xml"+"?nocache=" + my_Date.getUTCSeconds(),
                dataType: "xml",
                cache: false,
                success: function(xml) {
                    try {   
                        var data = $.xml2json(xml);
                        if(data.trade_type == 3 || data.rate_display ==0){
                            rates.marketstatus['goldrate'] = "";
                            rates.marketstatus['status'] = "0";
                        }else {
                            rates.marketstatus['goldrate'] = data.goldrate;
                            rates.marketstatus['status'] = "1";
                        }
                    }catch(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                },
                error: function(request,error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
        }); 
    }
}
```

This js file is my global file and included into my header.php file
and i have another page like goldbuy.php, here i have to get current gold rates from globalrates.js.

so that i have tried following code in buygold.js file

```
console.log(rates.marketstatus['goldrate']);
```

But it didn't work, how to use get and set method for javascript class.(class object created as like globalrates.js file)

Comment: `rates.marketstatus['goldrate']` should work. are you sure, you include your `globalrates.js` in your `goldbuy.php`? I'am assuming yes, if you include the `header.php` in your `goldbuy.php`. I think, the problem is, that you set an `interval` for 1 sec to set the rates. Because ajax is asyncron, you try to console log before those properties exists.

Comment: Try putting a console.log(...) statement in your success() callback, to make sure the service call is completing before you try to access the value.